# Algebra within probability statements

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, variance

I have the solution to my problem, but I don't understand how they went from one step to the next, I've circled the part I don't get.  Can someone explain this to me, or direct me where I can find the answer.  My book doesn't cover this typo of question and I'm not sure where to find the information.  I'd appreciate any help you can provide.

[image]

Comment: Notice that the random variable $$I_A(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1, & \omega \in A \\ 0, & \omega \notin A \end{cases}$$ takes only values in $\{0,1\}$. A crucial consequence is that you *always* have $I_A^2 = I_A$. The highlighted part is the consequence of this identity together with the linearity of $\mathbb{E}$.

Comment: The expectation operator is linear, does that help?

Comment: THANK YOU!   (min length comment)